# Fork() multiple children at once

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, multiple-processes

I am trying to create a c program where I fork a total of 4 children..

... When the first child is created, the parent waits until it finishes

... The last three children are forked (at the same time) and can finish at their own pace

... My code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MSGSIZE 16
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int status;
       
       if( fork() != 0)  // create a child
        {
            // we are in parent
               // Forking child 1
               wait(&status);
            if( fork() != 0)  // create another child
            {
                // we are in parent --> child 2
    
                  if( fork() != 0)  // create another child
                    {
                        // we are in parent
    
                          if( fork() != 0)  // create another child
                            {
                                 // we are in parent
                                 
    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // we are in the 4nd child
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // we are in the 3nd child
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                // we are in the 2nd child
                 // first child
             for (int a = 0; a < 50; a++)
             {
                 printf("a) %d\n", a + a / 2);
             }
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
             // first child
             for (int a = 0; a < 12; a++)
             {
                 printf("a) %d\n", a + a);
             }
    
        }
           
    
      exit(0);
    
    
    }//main
```

... When I run it my program ends, and reruns on its own.

**EXAMPLE**

```
a) 15
a) 16
a) 18
mrobinson@TOSHIBA312:$ a) 19
a) 21
a) 22
a) 24
a) 25
a) 27
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not re-running on its own. Your code does not wait for all children to complete before ending. So when the main/first process completes some of the children may still be running.

Comment: Where would you suggest I am the wait(&status), because if I add it at the end it defeats the purpose of the last 3 child forks running concurrently

Comment: So is it OK if the last 3 child processes are (possibly) incomplete when the parent exits?

Comment: "*it defeats the purpose of the last 3 child forks running concurrently*". Why would  that be the case? Waiting for them to complete does not prevent them running concurrently.

Comment: `} else } else } else } else` <<-- sorry, I am unable to read this.

Comment: Please edit the question to add some expected output/detailed behavior.

Comment: Your code would read better if you did something after a test other than start a new level of nested conditions.  Put your child activities into separate functions.  Test whether each fork fails, exiting if it did.  If the process is the child, call the appropriate child function.  Only if it is the parent do you proceed on to the next step (next child, next fork).  Reduce the clutter; make the code readable; use functions!